# php array_merge is not merging and is showing null

Tags: php

I have an $mentor_fails array which keep track of the mentors that failed to insert into the database table. Although, I am getting failed insertion exception but my $mentor_fails does not seemed to save the object containing the failed mentor information into $mentor_fails. Please let me know what I did wrong.

```
function assign_mentors_and_projects($mentors,$projects){
    global $mydb; 

    $mentor_fails = array();

    foreach($mentors as $mentor){
        foreach($projects as $project){
            try {
                $update_mentors_and_projects_rlshp = $mydb->insert(
                    'abcdefg',
                    array('project_id'=>$project, 'mentor_id'=>$mentor),
                    array('%s','%s'));

                    if($update_mentors_and_projects_rlshp == false) {
                        array_merge($mentor_fails, array('mentor_email'=>$mentor, 'project_id'=>$project));
                        throw new Exception("exist already:(mentor-".$mentor." project_id-".$project.")\r\n");
                    }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    return $mentor_fails;

}`
```

Comment: `array_merge` doesn't alter its arguments; you need to assign its *return value* to something.

Answer (score 1):

I think  the issue is that array_merge don't merge by reference .

From the [PHP doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php) :

> array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] ) : array

This snippet can resolve your issue.

```
$mentor_fails= array_merge($mentor_fails, array('mentor_email'=>$mentor, 'project_id'=>$project_id));
```

I see that you may add into $mentor_fails , so you can do it like :

```
$mentor_fails[]= array('mentor_email'=>$mentor,'project_id'=>$project_id);
```

Comment: I am still getting empty array with the snippet above : (

Comment: what's inside the $mentor_fails ?

Comment: do you want for each iteration , add a new element in the $mentor_fails ?

Answer (score -2):

to:

```
array_merge($mentor_fails, array('mentor_email'=>$mentor, 'project_id'=>$project));
throw new Exception("exist already:(mentor-".$mentor." project_id-".$project.")\r\n");
```

from:

```
throw new Exception("exist already:(mentor-".$mentor." project_id-".$project.")\r\n");
array_merge($mentor_fails, array('mentor_email'=>$mentor, 'project_id'=>$project));
```

Comment: You now have an unreachable statement.